# QR Code reading/writing in Ruby

Tags: ruby, pdf, qr-code, ruby-2.0

What's the easiest way to add QR Code reading/writing capabilities to a Ruby (2.0) program (if it helps, the codes will be written to and read from PDFs)? All of the gems I've found seem to have not been updated in quite some time, and usually have a ton of dependencies. Are there any good options out there?

Comment: This could help: http://jeromeetienne.github.io/jquery-qrcode/
it generates a QR code for a given string using JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the link (and I'd like to tinker with it in the future), but this project is using Ruby, not JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/smparkes/zxing.rb

YMMV, I'm the author. But I'm also the primary C++ maintainer of zxing and I use zxing.rb for a lot of testing so it should be as up-to-date as the C++ port is.

No comment on the number of dependences: they're not a barrier for me, obviously.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've been using ZBar so far but I'll definitely take a look.